# How to generate Logarithmic function from given point?

Tags: polynomials, logarithms, curves

I trying make player progression curve for my game design module. i have difficult to find up the curve to fit my description.

The given data (time , level) time in min and level is just a integer.

- (0,1) mean player start at level 1 in 0 min
- (5,2) mean player level up to level 2 in 5 mins from level 1
- (3000,30)mean player level up 30 in 3000 mins from level 1

any ideas to get the curve equation that describe these data?

Comment: why only 3 point will cause the possibilities endless?

Comment: Okay, perhaps there was some error in my equation. What I mean is, when you say: "Please fit a curve to my data", you should limit the possibilities because otherwise there are infinitely many expressions that can be fit to the data. You mention logarithms and polynomials in the question, so I assume that the function should have those. Also, since there are only three points, and they are even quite far apart, there's quite much "wiggle room" in between... That's why I said that the possibilities are endless.

Comment: So you should think about a **general form** for the equation that you want. Do you want something like
$$
y = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2
$$
or
$$
y = a_0 + a_1 \ln(x) + a_2 \ln(x)^2
$$
 or something completely different? Perhaps you can see where I'm going with this ...

Comment: Hello, i am unsure of form. i looking at https://medium.com/js-game-design-journals/graphs-for-player-progression-part-i-c56d83740450

my goal is from these 3 point i able to generate the form and put it in excel sheet and calculate the time taken between  level 2 to level 30 etc

Comment: I suggest a curve that is described by the function $level \mapsto time$. See [the formula given by WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate+%5B%281%2C0%29%2C+%282%2C5%29%2C+%2830%2C+3000%29%5D)

Comment: @Crostul thank , that help alot